# Determine a Key Pressed is Numbers in WinRT

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a WinRT Application,
I had overrided OnKeyDown Method, which has KeyRoutedEventArgs.

When I try to get the key from the arguments say args.key, I get Numpad4, Numpad5(incase Numpad is pressed) or Number4, Number5 in Numbers are Pressed.

How do I get only the Numbers say 4 or 5 in best way as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey

```
int number = -1 ; //invalid value 
if (event.Key >= VirtualKey.Number0 && event.Key <= VirtualKey.Number9)
{
   number = event.Key-VirtualKey.Number0;
}
if (event.Key >= VirtualKey.NumberPad0 && event.Key <= VirtualKey.NumberPad9)
{
   number = event.Key-VirtualKey.NumberPad0 ;
}
if(number!=-1)
{
     //enter code here
}
```